# How to measure the frequency of vibration of an ERM motor?

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor, motor-controller

I´m part of a team developing a device to produce a mechanical vibration whoose  frequency we can vary between 45 and 130 Hz. We are using an arduino with a potentiometer in order for us to vary the supply voltage in an Excentric rotating mass dc motor.Using a transistor as a switch we use the reading voltage in the potentiometer to supply  the base of the npn transistor. My questions are how can we measure the frequency of vibration knowing the voltage supplied to the motor? Do you have suggestions besides the ERM motor? And where to buy a specific motor for this purpose?

Comment: MEMS accelerometer? Smartphone app? Small magnet-and-coil arrangement?

Answer (score 1):

One revolution of the eccentric-weighted shaft should correspond to one cycle of vibration. The motor shaft speed should be directly proportional to the motor voltage. With a simple armature voltage control, using the armature voltage will not be and exact indication, but it might be close enough depending on the reason for determining the frequency. However, direct measurement of the frequency and displacement of the item under test may be required for a meaningful test.

If you have a motor with an eccentric weighted-shaft that is designed for the purpose of producing vibration, there would be no reason to look for something else unless there is some aspect of the operation that has not been described in the question.